# Why does calling Perl's exec builtin cause this function not to return to its caller?

Tags: perl, function, exec, return

I am having problems with passing arguments to a function and the called function not returning control back to the function that initially called it. Basically, I am reading in a text file which contains usernames and passwords into an array. Then using a foreach loop I am passing the username and password to another function but this never returns and only executes for one set of arugments;

```
sub batch {
    open(my $in, "<", "$ARGV[0]") or die "Can't open $ARGV[0]: $!";
 #Read file contents into an array.
 @listOfUsers = <$in>;
 foreach $listOfUsers (@listOfUsers) {
  #Regex to check if txt file conforms to correct syntax.
  if ($listOfUsers !~ /([a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,40})\s[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,40}/) {
   print "Please ensure that line $listOfUsers in $ARGV[0] is of the following syntax:\n";
   print "\n<USERNAME> <PASSWORD>\n";
   exit(0);
  } else {
   #split string and call AddUser function
   my ($username, $password) = split(" ",$listOfUsers);
   AddUser($username, $password);
  }
 }
}



sub AddUser {
 exec("infacmd.sh createUser -dn domain -un user -pd pass -hp domain:80 -nu " . $_[0] . " -np " . $_[1] . " -nf test");
}
```

Basically, don't worry what the AddUser function does. It just runs some .sh file that does some stuff that I'm not concerned about. Currently, I am only able to add one user from the file that I read in. I.e. this code only works once and does not return back to the 'batch' function.

I have tried adding 'return()' to the end of the 'AddUsers' function but this does not help

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

[`exec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html) never returns. Like the equivalent family of calls in UNIX C, it replaces the current process with the one you specify. You want [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html).

From those pages:

> **exec:**
> The `exec` function executes a system command **and never returns**; use `system` instead of `exec` if you want it to return. It fails and returns false only if the command does not exist and it is executed directly instead of via your system's command shell.
>
> **system:**
> Does exactly the same thing as `exec`, except that a fork is done first, and the parent process waits for the child process to exit.

---

If you want to capture the standard output of a program, you can use the `open`-with-pipe variant:

```
open (HNDL, "myprogram |") || die "Cannot execute.";
while (<HNDL>) {
    # Do something with each line.
}
close (HNDL);
```

---

The following transcript shows how you can search for lines containing a specific string (`123` in this case) from a specific command (`ls -al xx*` in this case):

```
pax> ls -al xx*
    -rw-r--r-- 1 pax None  10 2010-06-13 19:51 xx
    -rw-r--r-- 1 pax None 123 2010-05-05 23:39 xx.py

pax> cat qq.pl
    open (HNDL, "ls -al xx* |") || die "Cannot execute.";
    while (<HNDL>) {
        if (/123/) {
            print;
        }
    }
    close (HNDL);

pax> perl qq.pl
    -rw-r--r-- 1 pax None 123 2010-05-05 23:39 xx.py
```

Comment: arghhhh!!! *kicks self* thank you both so much. What if I want to employ backticks to execute this command instead? I want to be able to capture the output of the .sh command. :)

Comment: @microfly7, the usual way I do this in Perl is with the open-with-pipe variation - see the update.

Comment: The *and never returns* should be in italics.

Comment: After the .sh file runs, I just want to search to see if a particular error occurs. There won't always be an error.

So I want to see if the text "already exists" occurs, otherwise I don't care. Could you be kind enough and show me an applied example? Thank you.

Comment: @tchrist, I'm not entirely sure that's necessary since it should be pretty obvious from both that snippet and the rest of the answer that it doesn't return. However, if you think it'll improve the answer, sure thing, I'll emphasize it.

Comment: @paxdiablo: I **do** think it will improve the answer: why do you think I put in *perlfunc* in the first place? :)

Comment: @microfly7: You don’t ever want use `exec` unless you want to discard the currently running program and chain to the one you `exec`. Normally you use `ˋbackticksˋ` if you want to capture a program’s output, or `system` if you only care about its exit status.

Comment: Oh, _that_ `tchrist` - I guess I'll bow to authority on that one :-)

Comment: @tchrist: be patient; you will soon have sufficient reputation on this site that you can edit other people's answers as you see fit.

Comment: @Ether, I suppose. I haven’t been here a month yet.